# Do I really need to learn how to use registers - Programming a microcontroller?

Tags: stm32, register, stm32cubemx, hal-library

I have a curious question. Do I really need to learn how to use registers when I program a microcontroller?

I have been using Arduino for a long time. I quit using Arduino and starting to use STM32 because they are more cheap, faster and just better microcontroller. They do require more knowledge about C programming and what a microcontroller can do, because you can do more with STM32 than Arduino.

Anyway! I have tried to blink LED and read digital inputs e.g toggle with a STM32 by program it with registers. It's time consuming and painful. Luckily STM offer CubeMX so the user can setup a complete project with HAL-libraries without using any registers. Super easy and super fun!

This is how Atollic CubeMX looks like.

[image]

And now my real question, why I started this question.
I have been using Atollic TrueStudio. Works fine. But today I upgraded my Atollic TrueStudio and STM have implemented CubeMX into Atollic TrueStduio. Before I have to download both Atollic TrueStudio and then CubeMX. Seperate software in other words.

But today Atollic TrueStudio and CubeMX is merged together into one software. Great! That's really good.

But...to create a project for a STM32 microcontroller, you need to create a CubeMX project. There is no "Create a blank ARM project in C" as it was before. Now is like "You want to create a STM32 project? Well, you never going to use register anymore so we choose for you! Here, have a CubeMX with HAL-libraries project! Ready to run!"

Well...that's great! But do STM assume that working with registers is not necessary when I use STM32?

I have no problem to use SMT32 with CubeMX + HAL libraries. Not at all. But I'm worried if I become "stupid" if I use CubeMX + HAL just to make it easy for be.

Should I program a STM32 with registers or should I use CubeMX + HAL libraries? Notice that this is a 32-bit microcontroller of tons of documentation and not a simple AvRTiny8.

Today I create large projects with STM32 thanks to CubeMX + HAL libraries. I could never do that without this technology.

Here is the reason why I use STM32. It's just.....better if you compare the price and what you get.
[image]

Comment: Yes. You're not really doing embedded programming if you're not talking to the hardware.

Comment: @ThePhoton Ok. So I should get started with blank C projects instead of using the "cheat" CubeMX + HAL ?

Comment: CubeMX takes care of the initialization of STM32, so you don't have to.  You decide what you want, outputs, inputs, timers, etc and it installs the drivers to get you started.  It gets you over a rather big learning curve, so that you can concentrate on your application.

Comment: @Daniel, it depends if your goal is to learn embedded programming, or just to make whatever cool thing you are trying to make. If you just want to make something cool and you can do it with the register access hidden by the vendor libraries, then go ahead.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Yes. I know that. That's is why I have created large projects because I just declare the GPIO's so easy. Write less code too.

Comment: @ThePhoton I not only want to make something "cool". I want to make something that I can sell too. My goal is to be productive. I don't think companies today care about how smart you are if you going to work with software that do the heavy stuff :)

Comment: @DanielMårtensson, I haven't used STM32, so I don't know how good the HAL libraries are. For other products, from other vendors, I found the HAL library was vastly over-engineered and I preferred to re-write my own (covering only the functionality I needed).

Comment: As Photon says, it will get you started.  I roll my own or use CubeMX as required.  There are many aspects to learning, but at the end of the day, it is about making progress to some goal.  There are 6000+ Arm processors.

Comment: @ThePhoton The HAL-libraries of STM32 is like "WriteGPIO(GPIOchannel, GPIOpin, 1 or 0)" Done. Very easy.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I have always problem to getting started because each CPU has it's own documentation.

Comment: Each processor has 1000 pages.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat AVRTiny has about 200 pages.

Comment: Actually, I did almost all of my µC projects on various ATtiny as they are about the size of thing you can still handle when programming in assembler. Programs are rarely bigger than a few hundred bytes. It's fun, it's fast, it's versatile and you really learn something. For any bigger µC, programming in assembler isn't reasonable any more and if you aren't doing this you should ask yourself if you really want a µC, or if a tiny Linux machine isn't better suited. (There are use cases for "fat" µCs, but I haven't had one yet where a Raspberry Pi wasn't simpler **and** cheaper.)

Comment: @Janka I know that advanced problems need advanced solutions. But what if taking smart software to solve advanced problems with small solutions, e.g CubeMX = smart software.

Comment: Learn both ways.  professionally you want to be able to do either.  The HAL libraries are scary, just look at them, do you want to have your product rely on those?  But it saves you a lot of time and you can ask them for support/help easier than roll your own and they mostly work.  Roll your own you can have tighter, cleaner, more reliable code, but you have to do the work.  And sometimes that means read the HAL libraries (or other as they tend to have a couple out there at any one time) because the documents sometimes are not complete.  st generally really good with docs though.

Comment: No you dont NEED to, the chip vendors will at any time have one or more libraries that support an active product.  For various reasons they will release a whole new set of libraries at various intervals.  Which will cover the new products, plus maybe some of the not so old products, but not necessarily the old products.  So you may have more than one choice per product per vendor.  Older one is going to have more examples, newer one will have better support from the vendor.

Comment: The only time I wished for a HAL was when switching from Atmel to ST and guess what: that is the time it does not work!!

Comment: @old_timer I'm a Linux user and I found only Atollic True studio to work with Linux. Open Workbench works with Linux too, but I have heard that Atollic is far more powerfull then OpenWorkbench.

Comment: HAL is fine for toggling some LEDs, and it's a great tool to do the first steps in STM32 programming, but it just gets in the way when trying to solve some common tasks like receiving variable amount of data from a communications port, and it's [painfully slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440516/stm32-spi-slow-compute/) for tight timing requirements. Throwing in a faster STM32 might solve some timing issues, but when you try to sell your solution, someone will come along who can solve it with a STM32F0 for 1/4 the price, using the register interface.

Comment: @brendi why not use SPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do STM assume that working with registers is not necessary when I use
>   STM32?

Yes. They don't want you to bang the registers directly, because then they would have to document them properly and you would have to know about any differences between devices (including hardware bugs). By going through the Hardware Abstraction Layer you are shielded from all that and can concentrate on application code, which will then work without modification on different STM32 chips.

There may come a time when either the HAL libraries can't do what you want, don't have the performance you need, or have bugs you need to work around. Then you have a choice - learn the hardware and write your own code (preferably using the same HAL system), wait for ST to update the HAL, or go to another MCU with better support.

> Today I create large projects with STM32 thanks to CubeMX + HAL
>   libraries. I could never do that without this technology.

So you already have the answer.

In the past it was different because the HAL was poorly documented and CubeMX was full of bugs, so some of us tried to work without it - and failed. Banging the hardware is only tenable if you are a masochist with a lot of time to waste, or an expert who has already built up their own codebase.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer. I do have the time to dig into data sheets for hours. But I spend that time with friends, family and Java instead.  :) I have not found any bugs with latest CubeMX. Ok. Then I know that working with STM32, CubeMX is mandatory.

Comment: So STM32 documents are not proper written like Atmels?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson STM32 registers are documented in more detail than HAL functions.

Comment: @berendi Does all microcontrollers such as AVR, PIC have HAL-libraries?

Comment: Use the HAL libraries when you can; it saves work. But pick a function; (something simple like a timer, not an Ethernet controller!) and read through the HAL and driver source for it in detail. Find and understand how it translates simple requests into register bit operations. Then if you need to port from STM32 to some other arch where the HAL is missing, incomplete or buggy, you won't be stuck. Or if you need to port to ZYNQ or something where you can roll your own custom hardware, which obv won't come with a ready made HAL.

Comment: `some of us tried to work without it - and failed` - speak for yourself only. I failed many times using HAL (because of the bugs, poor STM people programming skills - probably first year not paid students from India)  - but newer using hardware registers directly. Arduino generation

Comment: @P__J__ yep, me too. But I'm a 62 year old curmudgeon who prefers to program in assembler. My STM32 project didn't get anywhere because I refused to use CubeMX and HAL libraries, but didn't have the patience to write all my own code from scratch. I would not recommend that path to anyone.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I have a "mixed" approach. I do not use assembler unless I really need to (but usually instrinsings are enough) and program in C. For the simple peripherals I use bare registers but it rather pointless to write USB or Ethernet stacks from the scratch. For that I use HAL. I also in all projects use RTOS-es (usually freeRTOS). Some of the projects are very large (700-800k of code) and I never failed :). BTW I am an old moron myself (52y)